# can't build xamarin android project

Tags: android, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I installed visual studio 2017 community on my new computer from scratch. I can build all my other projects and solutions. But when I try build my android app, I always get this error message:

```
The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csc.exe" is invalid.
```

And When I check the path, it really doesn't exist. I already tried reinstall xamarin, but without success. Any idea?

Comment: Did xamarin android project be created with VS 2015， then convert to Visual Studio 2017? If yes, try to create a new xamarin android project with Visual Studio 2017, if it works fine. If not, could you share more infoe about this issue, such as, how did you build the project, VS build or command build? what is the path of the msbuild.exe that you use?

Comment: Exactly, created in VS2015 and converted to VS2017. I created a new one and that worked. I now created a new one and moved all the code to the new project. But it's a but strange that it stopped working, since on my Notebook it worked with vs2017 aswell.

Comment: Did you only installed the Visual Studio 2017 on your Notebook? Or installed Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because that you created your project in Visual Studio 2015 and converted to Visual Studio 2017 without installed Visual Studio 2015 on the new computer. The path of csc.exe is different from Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017. The path of csc.exe in Visual Studio 2017 is:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn

To resolve this issue: You can **create a new xamarin android project in Visual Studio 2017, then copy all the code to the new project**.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

While Leo Liu-MSFT's answer is correct (probably, I haven't tested it myself), I did create a new project to compare the differences. It seems like projects created in 2015 have the following in the .csproj file:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Unix'">
   <CscToolPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin</CscToolPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

New (VS 2017) projects do not have this in the .csproj, so I opened the .csproj files in a text editor and deleted this tag. Everything seemed to compile and run just fine after reloading the projects in Visual Studio.

This is probably a more convenient answer for projects like mine where we have dozens of projects which would be a pain to recreate.